# Offline data storage/Sync options, Core Data, TouchDB or something else?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am creating a native iOS app and I have a set of REST services that I utilize to pull down data from the Web Server and store locally for offline use. It is a tremendous amount of data that the user will sync daily before starting work for the day.

At first, I thought about just using Core Data as I have used this before, but I am really not looking forward to recreating a schema that large in sqllite on the device.

I would rather store the JSON directly into a NOSQL database like TouchDB and query it from there if possible, but I'm concerned about memory consumption on the part of extracting the data. Core Data would allow for relatively low memory usage in this scenario, but comes at the cost of a lot of grunt work.

This is for a data entry application with 2000 data points per record and some of them are large text fields. The user can be offline for an entire day and needs everything local so they can go back and sync at the end of the day to get their work merged back into production and get their list of work for the following day.

So far I've been looking at TouchDB and CouchBase as alternatives for storing the JSON data. I've looked up several topics on SO regarding this and I've seen lots of folks using TouchDB and CouchBase, but for very small amounts of data. Like I said, my biggest concerns about moving away from my comfort zone of Core Data is performance and memory utilization when querying the data.

Comment: My take is if you want performance, do the grunt work for Core Data. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html)

Comment: @chrislhardin -- what did you end up using? Would you mind answering your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with Core Data... I believe it was the best choice at this time.